# Second derivative as a limit

Tags: real-analysis

This question is related with many similar questions seen around here. However, I'm under the impression that some of the answers may lack formalism because the author didn't request it.

I want to rigorously state a definition for the second derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ in terms of limits. My initial idea is that it should be

\begin{align}
f^{\prime\prime}(a)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f^\prime(a+h)-f^\prime(a)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left[\lim_{t\to 0}
\frac{f(a+h+t)-f(a+h)}{t}-\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+t)-f(a)}{t}\right]\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+h+t)-f(a+h)-f(a+t)+f(a)}{t}
\end{align}
with the last equality being valid because both limits exist in the line above it. However, I don't find this formula particularly illuminating and it is not clear to me how is it related with the formula

$$
f^{\prime\prime}(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+2h)-2f(a+h)+f(a)}{h}
\tag 2 \label{eq:2nd der} 
$$

seen elsewhere. My next idea was to go back to
$$f^{\prime\prime}(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f^\prime(a+h)-f^\prime(a)}{h}$$
and say that, if $f^{\prime}(a)$ and $f^{\prime}(a+h)$ both exist, then, for small $h$, the linear approximations
\begin{align}
&f(a+h)-f(a)=f^\prime(a)\cdot h+r_1(h)\\
&f(a+2h)-f(a+h)=f^\prime(a+h)\cdot h+r_2(h)\\
\end{align}
must be valid, where $\lim_{h\to 0}r_1(h)/h=0$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}r_2(h)/h=0$. With this, I would be able to write
\begin{align}
f^{\prime\prime}(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+2h)-2f(a+h)+f(a)-r_1(h)+r_2(h)}{h^2}.
\end{align}

However, it's not clear to me that $r_1(h)$ and $r_2(h)$ should satisfy
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r_1(h)}{h^2}=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r_2(h)}{h^2}=0$$
for the popular formula \eqref{eq:2nd der} to hold. I suspect that cases in which the limit in \eqref{eq:2nd der} exists even when $f^{\prime\prime}(a)$ does not is something related with the assumptions made about $r_1$ and $r_2$.

I'd like some help here. What is a formal definition of $f^{\prime\prime}(a)$ in terms of a limit?

Comment: If you take t and h equal the first limit becomes the second

Comment: @clark what are the assumptions that would allow me to do that?